# IE javascript form submit won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When submitting a form with javascript with onchange event chrome and ff work but ie does not. 
The dev console for IE displays:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
jquery-1.7.1.js, line 3175 character 6
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7ru3M/4/

EDIT: updated example. It works if you use the form directly but not if you use the link i created to select the file.

EDIT 2: http://jsfiddle.net/v84eh/3/ using only javascript still doesn't work. Clicking "browse" will run the script fine, clicking "Upload a file" will not.

Comment: I tried it, it worked. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: its working with IE8 and greater..Which version are you on?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery from a different domain? Like, a CDN or something?

Comment: I think you are using IE 7 or lower versions or else try tyo change the document mode and check.

Comment: I'm running IE 9 and yes I am using a CDN is that the problem?

Comment: @Adam It may or may not be. No idea. But if you change it to a copy that's stored in the same domain, does that help?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc let me check. hang on.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc no, that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: @httpete Not really. just ended up using: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader I found it very useful